# data from coredata is not showing on tableview in swift4

Tags: json, swift4

I am fetching json data and saving it in coredata. and calling it in  "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions". And when i am fetching the data in "viewDidLoad",  the problem is At the first time the tableview is empty. and when i am reopening the app after closing it then the data is showing in tableView.  Please see my programme

```
func fetchTopStories(){

    let moc = coreData.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let myUrlString = "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json?print=pretty"
    guard let newsUrl = URL(string: myUrlString) else { return }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: newsUrl) { (data, responce, err) in
        if err != nil{
            print("err in fetching data")
            return
        }
        else {
            guard let myData = data else{return}
            guard let jsonResult = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: myData, options: .mutableContainers) as? [Int] else{return}
            for i in 0..<jsonResult.count {
                let myString = "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/\(jsonResult[i]).json?print=pretty"
                guard let myUrl = URL(string: myString) else { return }
                URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: myUrl, completionHandler: { (data, responce, err) in
                    if err != nil{
                        print("err in fetching data")
                        return
                    }
                    else {
                        guard let allData = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary  else{return}
                       let news = News(context: moc)
                        if let newTitle = (allData!["title"]) as? String{
                            news.title = newTitle
                        }
                        if let newScore = (allData!["score"]) as? Int{
                            news.score = Int16(newScore)
                        }
                        if let newId = (allData!["id"]) as? String{
                            news.id = Int64(newId)!
                        }
                        if let newText = (allData!["text"]) as? String{
                            news.text = newText
                        }

                        if let newUrl = (allData!["url"]) as? String{
                            news.url = newUrl
                        }
                    }
                }).resume()
            }
        }
        }.resume()
    self.coreData.saveContext()
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are saving the CoreData stack after the indices have been received. At this moment none of the dictionaries are received yet.

You need `DispatchGroup` to get notified when all stories have been received and then save the context. Before creating the data task `enter` the group, in the closure `leave` it (also in the edge cases). `notify` is called after the last iteration.

```
func fetchTopStories() {

    let moc = coreData.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let myUrlString = "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json"
    guard let newsUrl = URL(string: myUrlString) else { return }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: newsUrl) { (data, responce, err) in
        if err != nil{
            print("err in fetching data", err!)
            return
        }
        else {
            let group = DispatchGroup()
            guard let jsonResult = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [Int] else { return }
            for anInt in jsonResult {
                let myString = "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/\(anInt).json"
                guard let myUrl = URL(string: myString) else { return }
                group.enter()
                URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: myUrl, completionHandler: { (data, responce, err) in
                    if err != nil {
                        print("err in fetching data", err!)
                        group.leave()
                        return
                    }
                    else {
                        guard let allData = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [String:Any]  else {
                            group.leave()
                            return
                        }
                        var news = News(context: moc)
                        if let newTitle = (allData!["title"]) as? String{
                            news.title = newTitle
                        }
                        if let newScore = (allData!["score"]) as? Int{
                            news.score = Int16(newScore)
                        }
                        if let newId = (allData!["id"]) as? String{
                            news.id = Int64(newId)!
                        }
                        if let newText = (allData!["text"]) as? String{
                            news.text = newText
                        }

                        if let newUrl = (allData!["url"]) as? String{
                            news.url = newUrl
                        }
                        group.leave()
                    }
                }).resume()
            }
            group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
                self.coreData.saveContext()
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

A few notes:

- Don't `pretty-print` if you are not going to print anything, the deserializer doesn't care about prettiness.
- Never ever use `.mutableContainers` in Swift. This option is completely pointless particularly you don't mutate anything and assign the result to an immutable constant.
- Don't use Foundation collection types `NSArray / NSDictionary` in Swift. Use native types.
- Never use ugly index-based `for` loops in Swift to iterate arrays. Use always Fast Enumeration, there is also a `for (index, element) in { ... }` syntax if the index is really needed.
- Print any `error` rather than an actually meaningless literal string `"err in fetching data"`.
- `guard let myData = data else{return}` is redundant. If `error` is `nil`, `data` is not `nil` and vice versa.

Comment: Hi Vadian , Thanks for your responce . Still facing this problem . i am fetching the data in  "viewDidLoad" .

Comment: func getData() -> [News] {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<News> = News.fetchRequest()
        request.fetchBatchSize = 16
        let formatSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "score", ascending: true)
        request.sortDescriptors = [formatSort]
        let results: [News]
        do {
            results = try managedObjectContext.fetch(request)
        }
        catch {
            fatalError("Error getting car inventory")
        }
        return results
    }

Comment: override func viewDidLoad() {
        coreService = Coreservice(managedObjectContext: coreData.persistentContainer.viewContext)
        news = (coreService?.getData())!
    }